# How does a single-qubit gate affect other qubits?

Tags: entanglement, pauli-gates

An instructional quantum computing article I'm reading ([How the quantum search algorithm works](https://quantum.country/search#how-to-reflect-about-the-s-and-E-states)) states that the following circuit takes $\vert x\rangle\vert 0\rangle$ to $−\vert x\rangle\vert 0\rangle$, when $\vert x\rangle$ is anything other than $\vert 00\rangle$.

[image: Reflecting across the all 0 state]

My question is: how can an operation (-Z gate) on the target qubit (the bottom one) affect the control qubits (the top 4 ones)?

I would expect the result of this circuit, when $|x\rangle$ is anything other than $\vert 0000\rangle$, to be $\vert x\rangle(−\vert 0\rangle)$. I understand that, algebraically, $(x)(-y)$ is the same as $-xy$, but intuitively, looking at this circuit, I don't see how those top 4 qubits would be affected by something happening to the bottom qubit. (I know, intuition doesn't have much place in quantum mechanics.) My hunch is that entanglement is at play.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to QCSE.  How are you interpreting $\vert x\rangle -\vert 0\rangle$? If $\vert x\rangle$ is four qubits, and (the bottom) qubit $\vert 0\rangle$ is only one qubit, then it's not clear that you can subtract only one qubit from four.

Comment: Hi! (Thanks for the edits.) I'm not interpreting it as subtracting |0⟩ from  |⟩. I'm interpreting it as -|0⟩ "next to"  |⟩. And what "next to" means, I have no idea! But it appears, from what I infer from the article, that |⟩−|0⟩ is the same as −|⟩|0⟩, so I assumed these objects follow the same rules as terms that are multiplied together (i.e.  ()(−) is the same as −).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phase of -1 generated on the ancilla is just a [global phase](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/329648/199113). You can shift it to any qubit [without affecting the statistics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/329648/199113) of the system. Nothing to do with entanglement.

Quantum mechanics is a mathematical framework that describes reality **insofar that it predicts the correct observable statistics** of a system. Shifting around a global phase factor from one qubit to another doesn't cause any deviation in the observable statistics and thus, they're all equivalent quantum states of the 5 qubits, **mathematically as well as physically**.

### $$-(|x\rangle\otimes |0\rangle) \equiv |x\rangle \otimes (-|0\rangle) \equiv (-|x\rangle)\otimes|0\rangle$$

---

As you're beginning to learn quantum computing you'll soon also hit another [conceptual block](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/why-does-the-phase-kickback-mechanism-work-in-the-quantum-phase-estimation-alg).

Though your question doesn't ask about it, I'll briefly point out a couple of things. For some reason people seem to believe that state of control qubits should not change when a controlled-$U$ gate is applied. The actual statement is that *only* the standard basis states $|\{0, 1\}^c\rangle$ ($c$ being the number of control qubits) remain unaffected by controlled-$U$ gates.

If the control qubits are in a state that is different from one of the standard basis states, then theoretically their state could very well be affected. Moreover, as Niel de Beaudrap beautifully illustrates [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2572/26), you should not attach too much significance to the standard basis!

The phenomenon is known as **phase kickback mechanism**:

> If we apply a controlled-$U$ gate to $|\psi_k\rangle$ (an eigenstate of $U$; $e^{i\phi_k}$ being the eigenvalue), $|\psi_k\rangle$ is unchanged, and $|0\rangle\langle 0| + e^{i\phi_k}|1\rangle\langle 1|$ is applied to the *control* qubit.
>
> [image]

For a detailed explanation, check [DaftWullie's answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2568/26) and the subsequent discussion in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an attempt to answer the question directly, but might help with the intuition. They key point is that multi-qubit gates can propagate the effect of a single-qubit rotation to other qubits. So, there's the technicality of *what* effect is propagated that I'll leave to other answers, but just to convince you that it *can* propagate:

Take a very simple circuit of two qubits. We apply the sequence SWAP - single-qubit rotation on qubit 2 - SWAP. I hope you'll agree that the net effect of this is simply that the single-qubit rotation is actually applied to the first qubit, not the second. So, it's all about those multi-qubit gates...