How does the phase kickback work in real hardware?
I have a trouble understanding the phase kickback, this figure from Kaye-Laflamme-Mosca's book summarizes the idea concisely;

Here is what I find:
When you do the calculations, you find that the phase is attached to the bottom qubit, somehow you are allowed to take this factor up to the top qubit, while this is possible by the axioms of the tensor product ( $|\alpha u\rangle|v\rangle =|u\rangle|\alpha v\rangle$ ) I am wondering how this is implemented in hardware?
The 'wires' represents qubits, how does a physical qubit 'transfer' its phase to another qubit? Or how do we 'force' this?

It probably helps to think about the controlled phase gate
$$
CP=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
You should really interpret this as "change the phase of the state if it's in $|11\rangle$". It's a collective operation, not localised to a single qubit.
Yes, it is convenient for us to think about this gate as controlled-$Z$: apply $Z$ to the target if the control is 1, and that leads us to thinking like the phase is being applied just to the target qubit. But that's the convenient classical description, not what it's really doing. It is a global operation that makes no distinction between which of the two subsystems the phase is applied to. This is perhaps emphasised even more strongly in this case in the sense that controlled-phase is symmetric - it doesn't matter which qubit you call the control, and which the target!

yes I understand this, thank you, still doesn't explain why this figure is drawn like that in that book, and why other books write the phases next to the top qubits and not the bottom one.

This is a basic property of the entangling gate. Then you do a cunning thing that is to choose a special, separable input state that is still separable after the application of the gate so that it happens to be the state of the control qubit that changes. The point being that while the phase can be anywhere, it is relevant to the top qubit in those specific instances.

If, as is here, the target qubit is prepared in $|−\rangle=\frac{|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt 2}$, then the phase is kicked back to the control qubit merely by operation of the controlled-$\hat{U}$ gate. The stuff that's in the dashed-circles of the figure just "happens". There's no special operation, apart from the controlled-$\hat U$ gate, that's needed.
But if your question is how the controlled-$\hat{U}$ gate is actually implemented, then this is hardware-specific. For example trapped ions (I think) use sophisticated versions of a Cirac-Zoller gate, while neutral atoms use a Rydberg blockade, and superconducting qubits use microwave-pulses. Given some (single-qubit) gate $\hat U$, it's mostly a purely mechanical procedure to convert this gate into a sequence of laser pulses or microwave pulses to make it into a controlled-$\hat U$.

Are you sure? When I do the math the phase is 'sticked' to the bottom wire, so initially it is on the bottom qubit, unless you have a way to 'force' the bottom qubit to stay on some phase, there is no way you can 'kick back' the phase.
If what you are saying was true, then there was no need for the authors of the book (and other books by the way) to show that this phase 'travel' from bottom to top. The question is now how it does travel physically?

Conventionally I’ve seen the control qubit see a Hadamard before and after the controlled-$\hat U$. It’s also stated that $|-\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\hat U$, so the target qubit doesn’t change. It “travels physically” because of the controlled operation

Also I’m not sure what you mean by the phase being “stuck” to a wire? The whole state is in a superposition of two qubits. The (relative) phase is not attached to a particular wire/particular qubit.

fair enough, the relative phase is not attached to any wire, but to all of them! Then how do you explain this other figure here https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/why-does-the-phase-kickback-mechanism-work-in-the-quantum-phase-estimation-alg?rq=1

also, if I understand correctly, an eigenstate means only the state can be multiplied, not that it cannot be changed, or am I wrong?

Regarding your second question $|-\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the (uncontrolled) $\hat{U}_{f(x)}$, meaning if we were to apply the uncontrolled $\hat U$ to $|-\rangle$, we’d get back $|-\rangle$ but rotated by a global phase. That’s what it means to be an eigenstate. The global phase is the eigenvalue. It’s unobservable when uncontrolled. But it’s a relative phase when controlled. It’s this relative phase that’s kicked to the control, because we are either applying $\hat U$ or not depending on the control qubit being $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$.

Now after reading your comment I am more confused, you are saying the opposite thing to that upvoted answer in the other post. To clear things out, let us just assume that there is no 'controlled' or 'uncontrolled' U, but just an operator CU which act on the whole state of the composite system.

I don't think I'm saying the opposite of @DaftWullie's answer. (BTW I was the one who +1'ed his answer). If you have a two-qubit gate, call it the NotaChoice gate, acting on a state $|\psi\rangle$ that's an eigenstate of NotaChoice, then all the NotaChoice gate will do is apply a global phase to $|\psi\rangle$ and will otherwise leave it unchanged. That's what it means to be an eigenstate. This global phase is unobservable in isolation. We can make this global phase a relative phase with a control qubit. I also like Craig's YouTube video here.

Anyways it's getting difficult to communicate further over comments. Please consider refining your thinking and maybe asking another question?
